# Conversion API Purchase Event does't work

Tags: rest, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-conversions-api

dear community!

I've encountered an issue while implementing the **Conversion API** integration on our website to track events and send them directly to Facebook from our server. We're experiencing problems specifically with the **Purchase** event.

What's particularly strange is that all event data appears correctly in the Ad **Campaign** table, **except** for the **Purchase** event. I've conducted test events, verified them in the **Payload Helper**, and everything appears to be configured correctly for optimization. However, optimization for the **Purchase** event continues to not work and seems to be completely ignored.

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "event_name": "Purchase",
      "event_time": 1695216450,
      "action_source": "website",
      "user_data": {
        "fbc": "fb.0.1695212450117.IwAR1yF9Jrf90FbSgflM_pJRYTgh7ZT3oymnFlrUNO40QTk86-UEnYSphNxF8_aem_AZOepfI1kP3x3UsCPVTzJ-MO0HygQ-6Vsk3yB8LwOV9PYzzhhWIYg7V1Ej4KBmwoYRxT1-6r0d7nyKtGcEiMibxh",
        "fbp": "fb.0.1695216450118.3823645",
        "country": [
          "02b0850aeac58c2cc82413170cdaf7ab69c28a00f04a8ee5744b52cd92c621e1"
        ],
        "client_ip_address": null,
        "client_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; Symphony Z60 Build/SP1A.210812.016; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/117.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/432.0.0.29.102;]"
      },
      "event_source_url": "https://somelink.com",
      "custom_data": {
        "value": 9.87,
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have the same problem... can't find solution

Comment: can your provide screenshot with purchase event settings from conversion api integration settings? (which params is you use for tracking, f.e. fbc, fbp etc)